# how do you resolve JLabel?

Tags: java

When I tried to compile my code it said that JLabel can't be resolved and I'm not sure why since it works for me in the past.

here's my code so far:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.JLabel;


  public class build extends JFrame
  {
    private JLabel item1;
    public build(){
      super("coin flip");
      setLayout(new FlowLayout());

      item1 = new JLabel("This is coin flip game");
      item1.setToolTipText("Hover");
      add(item1);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Also, many good IDEs will help you with this. Try NetBeans. :-)

Comment: JLabel can't be resolved ... doesnt look like an import issue..

Comment: Who thought this question showed research effort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import javax.JLabel;
```

Should be:

```
import javax.swing.JLabel;
```

Comment: Thank you I didn't even realize that.